# Google Play Games Crash On Initialization

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I use GPG in my game, but i don't create or set it yet. when i use:

```
    if(!PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
    }

    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate (success =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            ManageAchievements ();
        }
    });
```

it crashes my game. is it the problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1324988/android-game-crashes-on-startup-becaus-of-google-p.html), it seems that there is an incompatibility between the GooglePlayGames plugin and version 10.2.0 of the Google Play Services. Try rolling back Google Play Services to 10.0.1. It is also recommended to use `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated()` instead of `Social.localUser.authenticated` if you want to check whether the user is currently authenticated. It is also stated in this [forum](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1604) that crash occurs in `Social.localUser.Authenticate(...);` when trying to sign into the google game play services.

> [**Suggested workaround:**](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1604#issuecomment-280850233)
>
> Here is how I worked around this issue:
>
> 1. Go to Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Settings
> 2. Un-tick Enable Background resolution (This will suppress the update notifications once we downgrade the .aar files)
> 3. Go to \extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms
> 4. Inside each of the folders there are version folders (such as 10.0.1, 10.2.0). And inside those are the .aar files we need.
> 5. We will need the following files:
>
>    - play-services-ads-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-ads-lite-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-auth-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-auth-base-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-base-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-basement-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-clearcut-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-drive-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-games-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-gass-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-nearby-10.0.1.aar
>    - play-services-tasks-10.0.1.aar
> 6. Under \Assets\Plugins\Android delete the 10.2.0 versions of the .aar files above, with their META files.
> 7. Copy the 10.0.1 versions over
> 8. Build and run your project.
>
> If you don't do Step 2, Play Services Resolver will keep asking you to update these .aar files.
>
> I hope I was able to help anyone encountering this issue.
>
> Edit: Removed the image of the list of files and wrote them down instead. For easier copy-paste and indexing.

Hope this helps!